# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping With NotFound.Ignore() Disables Lazy Loading and Fetches Data Incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following two tables (schema simplified):

```
Device
    Id, IMSI, ...

SIM
    IMSI, PhoneNumber, ...
```

Because a device can use a SIM card that is not in the SIM table I'm using the following fluent nhibernate mappings in Device.Map class:

`References(x => x.Sim).Column("IMSI").NotFound.Ignore();`

This worked as expected until I wrote a query that returns all devices (a few thousand) and the memory usage sky rocketed.

The SQL profiler showed instead of generate one single query with join. Nhibernate generated one query to get all Devices and then thousands of queries to get the SIM for each Device.

I have tried adding Fetch.Join() in the mapping but got the same result.

I think Nhibernate should be able to generate a single query with a left join and get the same result. But I couldn't find out how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
var devices = session.Query<Device>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Sim)
    .ToList();
```

you'll get (almost) what you want.

NHibernate will generate a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between the tables, but still generate a separate `SELECT` for any `Device` without a corresponding `SIM`.

Comment: Thanks. Left join worked. But the separate queries are the real killer here. I'd expect the NotFound.Ignore in the mapping should prevent that from happening but it is obviously not the case.